# Windows explorer not working + virus

Tags: windows-7

This is definitely one if the stranger things to happen to me. I start up Windows normal as anything. I get this weird message box titled

> ubd.exe -entry point not found

and in the box it says

> the procedure entry `point_objc_init_image` could not be located in the dynamic link library objc.dll.

This is a problem in its own right but I think BitDefender takes care of it.

Anyway, Windows starts off normal and then after a couple of minutes things start to just not work. I can't press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, I can't click on any of the programs on the Start menu or type in the box and everything slows down (downloading, file scans). Somebody please help me.

Comment: can you boot into safe mode and run msconfig.exe to disable the startup program?

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like you have a virus. Here are the steps that you need to go through to make sure the computer is clean, and no virus/malware/potentially unwanted programs (PUP) are left behind:

1. Reboot to safe mode. This is done by rebooting the computer, and repeatedly pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> until the menu shows, and then click on **Safe mode with networking**.
2. Download ADWCleaner. Run it, clean whatever it finds and reboot the computer.
3. Download [Rogue Killer](http://www.adlice.com/softwares/roguekiller/) - either the 32Bit version or the 64Bit (depending on your computer). Start it (it takes a second to load the driver, do not be alarmed), run it, and when its done - click on Delete. Done.
4. Now you can run [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/), as third option, but make sure that when you start Malwarebytes you go to settings and allow it to threat PUP as malware. Very important step, as it might result in you having to click on all the pups it finds. There are also other apps out there, for example [TDSSKiller](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/tdsskiller/), Junkware Removal Tool, etc. But we are good for now.
5. Next thing that you need to do is to download [Avast](https://www.avast.com/en-us/index) - Free Antivirus, install and run. It will do a quick startup scan, which will find all viruses available, if any. The reason why you need Avast is - the other programs will take care of the bad malware, etc. However they do not remove viruses.
6. If you want to be 1000% sure nothing is left - scan with [ESET Online Scanner](http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner-popup/). When you download it make sure that: Under *scan settings*, check **Scan Archives** and **Remove found threats**. Click *Advanced settings* and select the following:

   - Scan potentially unwanted applications
   - Scan for potentially unsafe applications
   - Enable Anti-Stealth technology.

ESET will then download updates for itself, install itself, and begin scanning your computer. Please be patient as this can take some time. And by "take some time" - trust me, it WILL take a while. However, this tends to get everything that is hidden by the other applications that I listed.

Last, but not least - remove BitDefender, as it apparently does not do much to keep viruses away (for example - you do have a virus right now:-) )

I hope this helps!